# What memory type is a #define values assigned as?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Consider the following code, with various `#define` statements;

```
 #define PUSH 0x50
 #define POP  0x58
 #define NOP  0x90
 #define JUNK __asm__(PUSH, NOP, NOP, NOP, NOP, NOP, NOP, NOP, NOP, POP)
 #define J 0.752
 #define L 27
```

The first few states define some HEX values which are assembly instructions, and then a group of them.

The penultimate line defines a float called J.

The final statement defines a integer called L.

Are these memory definitions "typeless" as they are constants? I'm guessing not as I can't imagine how that would work. Does the compiler automatically assign the most relivant type such as float or int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these statements that has the `#` prefix, such as `#define`, `#include` and many others are not really C/C++ statements seen by the compiler. These are what is known as preprocessor directives.

The preprocessor is a piece of software that goes through all your code files before the compiler gets to process them. The preprocessor searches the files for special commands - known as preprocessor directives. Once it finds a directive, the preprocessor performs some manipulation on the code file. The compiler only gets to compile the result of preprocessing on the original code file.

For example, when the preprocessor encounters an `#include` directive, it simply replaces the `#include "whatever.h"` with the contents of the file `whatever.h`.  Only after the preprocessor finishes, the compiler gets to work on the resulting file - which has the contents of `whatever.h` already substituted for the `#include`.

`#define` is simply another preprocessor directive that is used to substitute some text with another piece of text.

```
#define PUSH 0x50
```

tells the preprocessor to replace a `PUSH` in a statement found in the file with `0x50`. The `0x50` has no type, it is not an integer or constant or anything, just a piece of text pasted into the original code file, replacing the text `PUSH` before it is passed to the compiler.

Once processed by the compiler the `0x50` text will be compiled according to whatever its syntax context is.

Comment: The `0x50` of your example is not “just a piece of text pasted into the original code file”. A macro replacement list is a sequence of preprocessing tokens; it has already been partially parsed. The tokens are substituted for the macro name, and the characters are not reinterpreted after substitution. So if a macro `x` is defined as `a-`, then `x>b` will not form the `->` operator in `a->b`.

Answer (score 4):

These are not "memory definitions".  They are preprocessor macros.  The compiler itself has no visibility of them, as they're all substituted (essentially by copy-and-paste) before it runs.

Comment: Thanks for the info Oli. When you say "copy-and-paste" do you mean the statements are replaced with the kind of code I would write before it runs, in the main body of a C file? I have seen on Wikipedia they are "preprocessor macros", but it's still not clear what happens why I type `#define J 0.752` for example.

Comment: @javano: I mean that the preprocessor substitutes any occurrence of `J` (as a standalone token) with `0.752` before the compiler itself runs.  This is essentially a text substitution; the preprocessor doesn't attempt to infer any meaning from the things that it's substituting.  The end result would be the same if you had done the substitution yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your macros will be literally replaced (substituted) by the character sequences they are defined to stand for before the compiler proper is invoked. I.e. your macros are not even "hex values". They stand for sequences of characters with no language-level semantic meaning attached to them.

After the substitution, these character sequences will be seen by the compiler proper and will be interpreted accordingly, depending on the surrounding context. In a "typical" case they be interpreted by the compiler proper as *integer constants*. Integer constants are *rvalues* in C, they have no memory associated with them. Conceptually, they don't exist in memory. That does not make them *typeless* though. In C the format of the constant defines its type. `0.752` is a constant of type `double`, while `27` is a constant of type `int`.

But again, the semantic meaning of the substituted sequence might (and will) depend on the context in which it is placed. You can "instantiate" these macros as string literals, if you wish, or concatenate them with other character sequences, thus completely changing their meaning.

Comment: Macros are not quite character sequences that are literally substituted. The replacement list is a sequence of preprocessing tokens. The tokens are substituted for the macro, and the characters are not reinterpreted after substitution. So if `x` is defined as `a-`, then `x>b` will not form the `->` operator in `a->b`.